# Missing log data - Standalone JBoss

Tags: logging, jboss

Ported a web app from another J2EE appserver to JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1.0.GA (Redhat Enterprise Linux 6). I am running an out-of-the-box standalone server.

Servlets and Jsp use System.out.println and System.err.println for logging. None of these log statements seem to show up in the server.log or console.log as i expected.

I realize i should be using a logging system, but where are these log entries vanishing to?

For instance, if i have the following in a jsp deplayed in a war file, where do these go?

```
<%
    System.out.println("TEST TO STDOUT");
    System.err.println("TEST TO STDERR");
%>
```

logging.properties

```
loggers=jacorb,com.arjuna,org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler,org.jboss.as.config,jacorb.config,sun.rmi

logger.level=INFO
logger.handlers=CONSOLE,FILE

logger.jacorb.level=WARN
logger.jacorb.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.level=WARN
logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.jacorb.config.level=ERROR
logger.jacorb.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.sun.rmi.level=WARN
logger.sun.rmi.useParentHandlers=true

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=CONSOLE
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush,target,enabled
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=FILE
handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,append,fileName,suffix,enabled
handler.FILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.fileName=/home/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/log/server.log
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.enabled=true

formatter.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.CONSOLE.properties=pattern
formatter.CONSOLE.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n

formatter.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.FILE.properties=pattern
formatter.FILE.constructorProperties=pattern
formatter.FILE.pattern=%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

standlone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.2">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up on System.out and System.err and started using Log4J as the logging system. Once setup, log4j works just fine. It was about time i started using a better logging system anyway. Strange thing is after setting up log4j, i see the System.err and System.out data in server.log as well. Not sure how it was fixed, but i am good now.